# Why won't register_setting() create a setting?

Tags: plugin-development, options, settings-api

I'm stumped. I've been researching this like crazy, but I can't seem to figure out why `register_setting()` isn't working for me. I'm new to WP plugin development (obviously), so it's probably just something silly that I'm missing. Check it out.

I'm running this in the constructor function:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'register_settings_and_fields') );
```

Then I have the following code which should execute what I need:

```
/**
 * Register the settings and fields for the plugin settings page.
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 */
public function register_settings_and_fields() {

    register_setting('my_plugin_settings', 'my_plugin_settings');

    add_settings_section(
        'my_plugin_main_section',                          // ID used to identify this section and with which to register options
        'Main Settings',                                   // Title to be displayed on the administration page
        array($this, 'my_plugin_main_settings_callback'),  // Callback used to render the description of the section
        $this->plugin_slug                                 // Page on which to add this section of options
    );

    // Begin defining the fields
    add_settings_field('my_plugin_data_1', 'Data 1', array( $this, 'my_plugin_data_1_setting' ), $this->plugin_slug, 'my_plugin_main_section');
}

// ... and of course other lines of code.
```

Of course, I have more code where I do things such as define the callback functions, etc. Everything seems to execute perfectly, and the settings section/field is displayed correctly. But when I go to `/wp-admin/options.php`, my_plugin_settings *has not been created*.

I'm stumped. Any thoughts? Let me know if you'd like to see more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you mean by saying that you can see your settings section and fields displayed correctly, but your my_plugin_settings has not been created.

I know sometimes I forget to add the actual admin part in which generally looks something like this:

```
settings_fields( 'my_plugin_settings' );
do_settings_sections( 'my_plugin_settings' );

submit_button();
```

Or is that you are having trouble when saving the form? If that's the case then I would need to see your callback function.

Sorry if this is not accurate to what you need, but I can;t currently comment on your question to clarify more before posting an answer. If this does not answer then let me know and I will adjust my answer accordingly.

EDIT #1:

I will be honest and say I am not 100% sure that the settings will automatically be added to the database. What I do right before adding the settings section and settings field is this.

```
/* If the options do not exist then create them*/
if ( false == get_option( 'my_plugin_settings' ) ) {
    add_option( 'my_plugin_settings' );
}
```

This will create the option in your database.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the response. I do have the the admin part that you listed already coded in. What I meant is that the actual html fields are added to the settings page correctly, but no `my_plugin_settings` field is added to the database. It's my understanding that JUST the `register_setting()` function alone should be enough to add the `my_plugin_setting` field to the database (although it wouldn't contain any data yet). Is that correct? I mean, after just running `register_setting()` I should see my variable listed on the wp-admin/options.php page, right?

Comment: Hey Pete just updated my answer but thought I would ask also, have you tried saving any data and then checking the database to see if they were created?

Comment: No, the settings aren't automatically added to the database by `register_setting()`. The setting won't be added to the database until the form is submitted.

Comment: Awesome! Got it. Just a matter of my poor understanding of how that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in my case what solved the problem after debugging options.php regarding the $whitelist_options variable, was to make the **$option_group** argument the same as the options page slug.

In your example

```
register_setting($this->plugin_slug, 'my_plugin_settings');

add_settings_section(
        'my_plugin_main_section',                          // ID used to identify this section and with which to register options
        'Main Settings',                                   // Title to be displayed on the administration page
        array($this, 'my_plugin_main_settings_callback'),  // Callback used to render the description of the section
        $this->plugin_slug                                 // Page on which to add this section of options
    );
```